# VSCode File encoding unexpectedly switches to UTF-8 whereas "settings.json" states that the encoding should be windows-1252

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code version 1.63.0 on Windows 10

[image: Visual Studio Code version 1.63.0]

I have set up my VSCode such that all *.pl files are encoded in Windows-1252, see my settings.json below:

[image: settings.json]

This works correctly when I open a folder in VSCode, for example: I right-click on the folder "Test" and then Open with VSCode. I can see that the encoding is Windows-1252. This works correctly, no problem here:

[image: Encoding-1252]

However, if I right-click on the file directly and then open with VSCode, the encoding is unexpectedly UTF-8. This is not what I expect. I expect that the encoding is always Windows-1252 as specified in my "settings.json", regardless of how I open VSCode.

[image: Encoding UTF-8]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I have found a work-around: (it is not ideal, but it works). From the DOS prompt, if you want to open a file in VSCode, simply open the folder first, like so -- C:\>code . && code Test01.pl -- In fact, this opens the folder first, then it opens the file in a second step.
Now the encoding ("Windows 1252") is correctly set up.